# typescript: create a function accepting IncomingHttpHeaders as parameter

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to call this function

```
checkHeader(req.headers['my-header'])
```

with req being a `IncomingMessage`

If I define checkHeader like this:

```
const checkHeader = (h: string | string[] | undefined) => {
```

It works fine, but if I define it like:

```
const checkHeader = (h: IncomingHttpHeaders) => {
```

I get the following error:

```
lib/api.ts:87:17 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IncomingHttpHeaders'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IncomingHttpHeaders'.
```

Also tried with:

```
const checkHeader = (h: IncomingHttpHeaders | undefined) => {
```

With the following error:

```
lib/api.ts:87:17 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IncomingHttpHeaders | undefined'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IncomingHttpHeaders | undefined'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IncomingHttpHeaders` is the type for the whole headers map (i.e. what is in your `req.headers`), it is not the type of individual headers. If you really want to get the type of all possible values of that mapping you can do:

```js
const checkHeader = (h: IncomingHttpHeaders[keyof IncomingHttpHeaders]) =>
```

But this is quite awkward as you can see.

Comment: mmmm, I see, isn't there some `IncomingHttpHeader` (in singular) I could use? Is your suggestion the right way to do it ('cause it is awkward indeed)

Comment: I guess I could also deine my own `IncomingHttpHeader` type as an alias to `string | string[] | undefined` ... right?

Comment: Yes, if you want to reuse this, you could define your own type, however a general  recommendation would be to extract all necessary values out of request in a single place and then propagate a well structured and more type-safe object in the rest of your application.